# Securing a RESTful API

Tags: security, api, authentication, rest, restful-authentication

For my current side project, which is a modular web management system (which could contain modules for database management, cms, project management, resource management, time tracking, etc…), I want to expose the entire system as a RESTful API as I think that will make the system as more usable.  The system itself is going to be coded in ASP.MET MVC3 however if I make all the data/actions available through a RESTful API, that should make the system very easy to use with PHP, Ruby, Python, etc… (they could even make there own interface to manage certain data if they wanted).

However, the one thing that seems hard to do easily (from the user's using the RESTful API point of view) with a RESTful API is security with ajax functionality.  If I wanted something that was complex to setup and use, I would just create SOAP services but the whole drive for using a RESTful API is that it is very easy.  The most common way of securing a RESTful API with with a key that is associated with a user.  This works fine when all the calls are done on the server side however once you start doing ajax functionality, that changes.  I would want the RESTful API to be able to be called directly from javascript however anyone who are firebug would easily be able to access the key the user is using allow that person access to the system.  Is there a better way the secure a RESTful API where it does not make the user of the RESTful API do complex things just to set it up?

Comment: See also [REST authentication and exposing the API key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472668/rest-authentication-and-exposing-the-api-key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, you can't prevent the user of your API to not expose his key.

But, if you are writing a client for your API, I would suggest using your server side to do any requests to the API, while your HTML pages provide the data from the user. If you absolutely must use Javascript to make calls to the API and you still have a server side that populates the page in question, then you can obscure the actual key via a one-way digest algorithm in a timestamp-dependant way, while generating the page, and make it that your api checks that digest in a time-dependant way too.

Also, I'd suggest that you take a look into OAuth Nonces and timestamps a bit more deeply. Twitter and other API providers obviously have this problem too, so they must be doing something with the Nonce values.

Comment: I understand I can't prevent the user from expose their key, I would like to be able to try to provide a way for both server and client side to make requests to the API.  I will look into digest access authentication more closely.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make some signature in request from javascript. But I'm hot sure, how 'RESTfull' urls would be with this extra info. And there you have the same problem: anyone who can see your making-signature-algorithm can make his own signature, witch you server will accept as well.

Answer (score 0):

SSL stands for secure socket layer. It is crucial for security in REST API design. This will secure your API and make it less vulnerable to malicious attacks.

Other security measures you should take into consideration include: making the communication between server and client private and ensuring that anyone consuming the API doesn’t get more than what they request.

SSL certificates are not hard to load to a server and are available for free mostly during the first year. They are not expensive to buy in cases where they are not available for free.

The clear difference between the URL of a REST API that runs over SSL and the one which does not is the “s” in HTTP:

```
https :// mysite.com/posts runs on SSL.
http  :// mysite.com/posts does not run on SSL.
```