# Login with Facebook and User Registration in a Mobile App

Tags: android, facebook, security, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I have an Android application that provides users to use it by their Facebook accounts. For this purpose, I have integrated Facebook login. However, I confused about the user registration by Facebook.

When the user logged in, Facebook provides userId, email and access token. I can use them to create an account for the user at my back-end. Let's demonstrate the scenario:

User comes first,

```
    1- User logged-in by Facebook.
    2- The email is checked by server and returns no such user
    3- An account is created by the information from Facebook
    4- The user keeps using the app with this account.
```

User comes again,

```
    1- User logged-in by Facebook.
    2- The email is checked by the server and returns that there exists a user.
```

In right here, here are the questions:

1- How can the server trust the request that it is from really Facebook so the server can respond to the app "he can log in"? To be sure, should I verify the access token by connecting to Facebook at server side too?

2- If not, how can a user be registered by using the Facebook login in a very safe way?

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497477/how-to-use-facebook-login-to-access-data-from-backend-server-in-android-app), but there is no answer as a solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have researched and finally decided to apply the following steps:

**1-** The app logins with Facebook and get access token, e-mail, name and userId.

**2-** The app connects to the API (the server side), sends the information gathered from Facebook

**3-** The server gets the access-token and verify it by using the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={ACCESS-TOKEN}
```

It returns the following:

```
{"name":"{USER-NAME}","id":"{USER-ID}"}
```

**4-** The servers checks whether the both user ids are same. If they are, it verifies the token is from Facebook and the information can be used for login/register.

**5-** The server checks whether the email/user id(fb id) exist at the system. If it doesn't, a user is created (the register process is trigged). If it does, login is set as success and the server returns the user information with access-token and refresh-token which are just generated.

**6-** The other operations are all performed by using those access and refresh tokens in the way of oAuth approach without connecting Facebook again.

Everytime the app is opened, `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` brings the access-token from Facebook. If it is null, user will see login screen. If it is not, the steps above will be applied.

**Good Questions and Answers Related This Topic:**

[REST API for website which uses Facebook for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065492/rest-api-for-website-which-uses-facebook-for-authentication)

[Architecture Design - REST API to support Facebook Login done by Mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230482/architecture-design-rest-api-to-support-facebook-login-done-by-mobile-app)

About already existing users, merging operations, and data structure suggestions from Facebook itself :

[Essential Guides of Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login)

[Using Facebook Login with Existing Login Systems](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/multiple-providers)