# Facebook integration for mobile app with a backend REST API

Tags: android, ios, django, facebook

We're building mobile apps (iOS and Android) that require a REST API backend and integration with Facebook for authentication.

I'm still confused on what is the best architecture design for this kind of use case.

Main Question: **Who is responsible for authenticating/authorizing with Facebook, client or server?**

**Option A:** Client authenticates to FB. Client sends requests using the token it received from Facebook. Server uses that token to identify the user.

**Option B:** Server authenticates to FB in behalf of the client.

*Additional notes (may be relevant or not):*

- *I'm developing the REST API part using Django.*
- *The app will need access to the user's Facebook friends so we can invite them to use the app.*

Comment: Is your rest api supports login with e-mails as well? What other options are you looking to implement with facebook (getting friends list of your user, etc)?

Comment: @MuchOverflow Currently, login will be purely Facebook only. We also need to share content to the user's Facebook friends.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27295322/165106 has a good explanation why option B is the better one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should go with option A.

- Authenticate with the client. Then you will receive an access token.
- Send this token to the server.
- Now you can create a user, fetch FB friends, and all other  you might need.

If you are using django-rest-framework, you should have a look at the django-rest-auth package. It handles user login/creation on the server side using the access token.

https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#social-authentication-optional

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [Facebook SDK for Python](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk), it should tell you how to incorporate it into your app and it shows how to integrate with a few frameworks [here](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (Flask being similar to django for this).

Facebook will be doing the authentication on their side, not you, though you may want to store the user's token in a database.

Comment: If I do it on the server side, then the server needs to ask the user's Facebook's credentials, correct? And then send it the FB for authenticating.