# Facebook Login with existing authentication system: how to pass the api token to the client?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, oauth, facebook-login

I'm working on an Android app where there is an existing authentication system, based on email/password.

Whenever the user successfully logs in with username and password, a *JWT token* is created and returned to the app for making the authenticated calls.

Now I want to support Facebook Login, however some steps of the OAuth communication are not super clear to me. I searched the documentation but it seems to be a bit vague.

This is the process as I envision it:

1. User clicks on Facebook button
2. The app asks to the server a *state token* `821379812739871293` and calls the FB url configured like so
   `https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=123&redirect_uri=https://<myappdomain.some>/fb-callback&state=821379812739871293`
3. The app opens a webview where the user can accept to login and share the email address
4. Facebook redirects to `redirect_uri` with something like this `https://<myappdomain.some>/fb-callback?code=h21i3i2h13&state=821379812739871293`
5. Within the callback call, the server:

   - checks if `state token` exists otherwise it rejects the FB callback
   - it uses `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/oauth/access_token` to obtain the `access_token`
   - it uses the FB APIs to retrieve the email address (have to check how to do this, but should be enough to call `/me`)
   - if email exists (sometimes it does not) it tries to find an existing user in the DB or adds a new one
6. **[ UNCLEAR PART ]** The callback returns a redirect to some OS-registered URL like `http://<myappdomain.some>/login-success?apiKey=<jwt-token>`
7. **[ UNCLEAR PART ]** the app reads the API key from the URL and proceeds making the calls to the backend

Is this correct/common practice?

Thanks!

EDIT: to clarify, I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065492/rest-api-for-website-which-uses-facebook-for-authentication?rq=1), however it is bad practice to store the client secret on the app side.
Moreover, in future I might integrate Instagram and LinkedIn authentications which seem to not allow or discourage bypassing the server with implicit oauth.