# How to secure Rest Based API?

Tags: rest, post, get

We intend to develop rest based api. I explored the topic but it seems, you can secure api when your client is an app (So there are many ways, public key - private key etc). What about websites / mobile website, if we are accessing rest based api in website which do not use any login for accessing contents ( login would be optional ) then how could we restrict other people from accessing rest based api ?

Does it make sense using Oauth2.0 ? I don't have clear idea of that.

More clear question could be ,How can we secure get or post request exposed over web for the website which doesn't use any login ?

If it's simple get request or post request , which will return you json data on specific input, now i have mobile website , who will access those data using get request or post request to fetch data. Well, some else can also access it , problem is i am not using Login, user can access data directly. But how can we restrict other people from accessing that data.

Comment: What do you mean by 'secure'? i.e. what threat are you trying to protect against?

Comment: Ok, it's simple get request or post request , which will return you json data on specific input,  now i have mobile website , who will access those get request or post request to fetch data. Well, some else can also access it , problem is i am not using Login, user can access data directly. But how can restrict other people from accessing that , thanks for the response

Comment: For access through websites, see also [REST authentication and exposing the API key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472668/rest-authentication-and-exposing-the-api-key).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you think is the difference between securing a website that is not using REST vs one that is using REST API?

OAuth provides authorisation capabilities for your site, in a REST architecture this means a user of the mobile application will have to provide their credentials before being allowed to access the resource. The application can then decide on if that user has access to the requested resource. However you've said your website doesn't need use authorisation.

You can use certificates however good luck managing the certificate for each client. My take on it is for your explanation you don't need to secure your website because you will never be able to manage a trust relationship between the client and the server. There are some options though:

1. You build your own client application that you ship out to people which can verify itself with the server using a packaged certificate with the client. E.g. iOS has this kind of feature if you build for that device.
2. You provide a capability to download a certificate that is 'installed' in the browser and used when communicating to your REST API
3. Use something like a handshaking protocol so when a client wants to make the first request it says; 'hi I'm a client can we chat?' And the server responds with 'yes for the next X minutes we can however make sure you send me this key everytime you tell me something YYYYYY' (you can use something like [SecureUDID](http://www.secureudid.org/) or equivalent for other devices than iOS).

There are probably others but you get the basic idea. Again in my opinion if your resource doesn't need authorisation then you don't need to secure that REST API. Can I ask what kind of data are you exposing via this REST API or functionality your providing? That might help provide a better answer.

Comment: Hi ,  The data is in JSON format, it will be json object containing simple data like Text Field Values , Numbers , Description for the Object, this will be populated in Web UI

Comment: Yes, because it will be core information for website, if this is accessible without login, it means anybody could use our service to get data and they will publish in their private apps/websites

Comment: you can't secure a website unless you issue a key/certificate to everyone that will be access your website or alternatively you need to re-think using a login!

Answer (score 1):

You want authorization: only some agents (mobile clients) and/or users should be allowed to access those APIs.

To solve that problem, you need identification: a way for the server to tell who is who (or what), so the right decision can be made.

There are many different way to provide some form of identification, depending how much you care about security.

The simplest is a user agent string, specific to your mobile clients. But it can be faked easily. Slightly harder to fake are client based 'secrets' - embed some kind of secret or key in your mobile client code. You can make it really complicated and secret, but as ramsinb pointed out, you can't get security this way as it would require you to be able to guarantee that the secret you're shipping with the client (wether it's code, algorithm or any other fancy construct) can't be compromised or reverse engineered. Not happening when you don't control the client.

From there, 3 choices:

1. Security isn't really required, don't bother
2. Security isn't really required, but you still want to limit access to your API to either legit users/agents or people ready to invest some time hacking your protection - go with a specific user agent or a client embedded secret - don't invest much into it as it won't block people who really want access to get it anyway
3. Security IS required - and then I don't think there is a way around authentication, wether it's login/password, user specific (device specific?) keys, OpenID, etc... No matter what, you'll have to add to the user burden to some extent, although you can limit that burden by allowing authentication to persist (cookies, storage....)